# C#: Save image error

Tags: c#, image, drawing

i am trying to save a new image, but then C# give me an error like the following image [image]

the error refer to the following code

```
string oldfilename = valid.getStringBeforeAnyChar(fi.Name, '.'); //"1"
string newfilename = FolderDir + "\\" + subfolderoutput + "\\" + oldfilename + Copyright + fi.Extension;
//"C:\\Users\\RHIT ! Solution\\Desktop\\direktori\\Output\\1[Watermarked by : RHIT Watermarker ].png"
try
{
    imgPhoto.Save(newfilename, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // <-- error here
    imgPhoto.Dispose();
    imgWatermark.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

where did i go wrong ? how to resolve this ? i don't know can be an `output` folder limit to create a new file

Comment: Is that colon `:` in your filepath? Filepaths do not allow colon's (`:`).

Comment: Yes ! You are right ! so, what are the character that prohibited in filepath ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions There is a list, I'll add as an answer with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows File Paths do not support the colon (`:`) character, as well as several others for file names:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions

In summation; invalid characters are:

1. `<` (less than)
2. `>` (greater than)
3. `:` (colon)
4. `"` (double quote)
5. `/` (forward slash)
6. `\` (backslash)
7. `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
8. `?` (question mark)
9. `*` (asterisk)

The backslash (`\`) character may appear only when used as a folder/directory delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly something wrong with `newFileName`. You can view the value of this in the debugger to see what might be amis with the intended filename & path.

As a general piece of advice though, it is better to combine directory and file name into a path using `Path.Combine()` which sorts out lots of potential issues like double or missing '\'.

Comment: Does `Path.Combine()` automatically generate subdirectory when the subdirectory is missing ?